# How to combine two if statements in PHP for WP

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I need to run a function (show a modal) **if** a page **DOES** have a particular field value **AND is not** a certain page. It also needs to work if the page **DOES NOT HAVE THE FIELD VALUE** and it is not the certain page. They work individually like this:

//if page has field value:

```
<?php
    $values = get_field( 'recast_video' );
    if ( ($values) ) {
        get_template_part('template-parts/popIn', 'none');
    } 
?>

//if it is this page, do not show:

<?php
if ( (!is_page('trading-education-webinars') ) ){
    get_template_part('template-parts/popIn', 'none');
} 
?>
```

How do I combine the two so that it shows (get_template_part) if the field **has the value** and **is not the specified page**

```
//this fails

<?php
    $values = get_field( 'recast_video' );
    if ( ($values) || (!is_page('trading-education-webinars') ) ){
        get_template_part('template-parts/popIn', 'none');
    } 
?>
```

Comment: And, not Or....

Comment: change || to && in if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is look for the common condition. No matter what, you don't want it to be a certain page, right? So first check that it's not that page:

```
$result = (!is_page('trading-education-webinars')) ? : ;
```

> It also needs to work if the page **DOES NOT HAVE THE FIELD VALUE** and it
>   is not the certain page.

Then why check for the field value at all? No need, as long as it's not the page we checked for.

```
$result = (!is_page('trading-education-webinars')) ? get_template_part('template-parts/popIn', 'none') : return false;
```

You can change `return false;` to whatever you want to happen if the page IS 'trading-education-webinars'

EDIT: Clarifying the conditional:

- Page X never gets served "content" (modal)
- If NOT page X and has $values, show content
- If NOT page X and NOT has $values, show some other content

$values = get_field( 'recast_video' );

```
$x = get_template_part('template-parts/popIn', 'none');

$y = 'some other content';

$return = (!is_page('trading-education-webinars')) ? (($values) ? $x; : $y ) : return false );
```

Comment: I think I was incorrect in my specs, sorry man. There are other pages that have the field value, and should show the content. If the page isn't 'trading-education-webinars' and doesn't have the field value, they should NOT show the content.

Comment: Does 'trading-education-webinars' ever get shown the content?

Comment: No, never. Each one evaluates correctly on its own, but when I combine if the first part fails, it doesn't evaluate the second part - 'short circuit'. Is this where the 'bitwise And' would work?

Comment: If the page has the field value and is not page X, show content. If the page doesn't have the value and is not page X, don't show the content. If the page doesn't have the field value and IS page X, don't show the content. If the page does have the field value and IS page X, don't show the content. Is this correct?

Comment: page is not page X and No Value - show content. Page is Page X and value - do not show. Page is Not page X and no value - do not show. Page is Not page X and value - show. would never show on page x regardless of value (which it will never have)

Comment: I realize this is convoluted, is there a way to start a private discussion or would you like me to edit original question?

Answer (score 1):

Use the && (AND) operator:

```
<?php
    $values = get_field( 'recast_video' );
    if ( ($values && !is_page('trading-education-webinars')) || (!$values && is_page('trading-education-webinars')) ){
        get_template_part('template-parts/popIn', 'none');
    } 
?>
```

|| operator is true when at least one or both statements are true

Comment: that will only work if the $values is true AND it is not the specified page... right? Will it also work if $values is false AND IT IS NOT the specified page?

Comment: No it won't. Result of `&&` true when both operands are true.

Comment: first option, when BOTH statemets are true then, and only then the result is true

Comment: please see edited question. I didn't specify the third case. It needs to work if the field is empty, but is not the specified page also.

Comment: updated my answer, use || and then two cases separetly

Comment: It still doesn't work if the field is empty and it si not the specified page. Nothing loads in that case

Comment: It also needs to work if the page DOES NOT HAVE THE FIELD VALUE and it is not the certain page.

at the if statement, the second statement is_page should be !is_page

Comment: Nothing seems to work. The statements, if singular work but when I combine them, no matter the order they fail. Is this because the operators 'short-ciruciut' and dont evaluate both?